# C# How to retrieve the "Command line"(exec. statement) of a process running through the process ID

Tags: c#

Dear Stackoverflow community,

I'm a beginner in programming, I'm building a small application.

I am having difficulty with the following problem:

- Input: ID of a running process
- Output: The command was executed when running that process (as shown).

In my application, I tried using: System.Diagnostics.Process and System.Management.ManagementObject but I could not find the attribute to look for,

I would be grateful if someone suggested to me the solution to this problem.

Thank you.

[See pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBioK.png)

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track with `System.Management.ManagementObject`, and you are looking for the `CommandLine` property. You need to pass the constructor a WMI path to the object, in your case `Win32_Process.Handle=6316`. For example:

```
string GetProcessCommandLine(int processId) =>
    System.Management.ManagementObject("Win32_Process.Handle=$processId").CommandLine;
```

---

Alternatively, according to https://serverfault.com/questions/696460/given-a-pid-on-windows-how-do-i-find-the-command-line-instruction-that-execute , you can execute the following WMI query:

```
SELECT CommandLine FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessID = <your process ID>
```

You can accomplish this from C# with a [`System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobjectsearcher(v=vs.110).aspx). At the end of the day this will return the same `ManagementObject` as above anyway (with only the `CommandLine` property populated). For example, something like the following ought to work:

```
string GetCommandLine(int processId) =>
    System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(
        "select CommandLine from Win32_Process where ProcessID = $processId")
    .Get()[0]
    .CommandLine;
```

Comment: Incredible! I am really grateful to you! Wish you a good day! Thank you.